# Как снять ограничение на количество символов в postgresql у всех таблиц и полей в бд?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Есть огромная база данных, вручную мне придется менять стандартное максимальное значение символов (до этого ставил varchar(99999), что бы проблем не возникало с внезапно падающей бд из-за превышения встроенного ограничения)

Создаю все сущности и отношения с помощью sequilize по типу

```
const Variant = sequelize.define('item_variant', {
    id:                  {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
    name:                {type: DataTypes.STRING,    allowNull: false },
    categoryId:          {type: DataTypes.INTEGER,    allowNull: false },
})
```

Comment: Тип `TEXT` не подойдет?

Comment: что такое "стандартное максимальное значение символов" и что такое "внезапно падающей бд"? postgresql даёт ограничение 1гб на размер одного text или varchar. Тогда как ограничение varchar(N) - это не лимит базы, а ваш. Вы сами его выставляете там где вам нужно и именно такой какой вам нужно. Дефолтного N у varchar нет.